# Removal of List elements from another Lists?

Tags: picklist, list, product

There are two lists (UserProduct And List Product), each of them holding Product code and Product Name.

On selecting a particular user from picklist UserProduct Lists displays Products based on picklist value and ListProduct displays all the Products in org. Including Products displayed in UserProduct Lists.

How to remove the Products of UserProduct List displayed in ListProduct Lists?

Comment: Are you talking about an apex or javascript controller?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `List.clear()` method right before refilling the list.

Here you can see the reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_clear